# Domain values in Attribute sidebar window drop down not reflecting values in Domain properties after editing values in Geodatabase Domain

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, domains

I have a File Geodatabase with a Domain called "Pipe Material" and it has about a dozen values listed in it.  These have been applied to feature classes for a bit.  We recently reduced the number of materials in the Domain values after re-coding the records in feature classes under those Domains.  For example incorrectly coded "C" value records became "CONC".

I went into the properties of the Domain in the Geodatabase properties and cleaned up the list, removing "C" but leaving "CONC" etc.

However when I am in an edit session and create/edit a feature that uses this Domain, I am not seeing the proper Domain values in the drop-down list of the attribute sidebar window, nor do I see the correct values in the regular attribute window's drop-down list for the Domain on that field.  I am still seeing values i have deleted from the Domain.

How can I make sure only values in the Domain are available in the attribute's drop-down list?

Comment: Create lookup table, old/new values, join to table using old and populate new column with new. Remove join, populate original.

Comment: I am not looking to change the values in the records, that is already done, I am more concerned with limiting the values in the lookup table when someone creates a new feature in the future.  Currently all the old domain values are showing up still even though the domain in the geodatabase does not show those values as part of the domain.